# Docker image has no signer when running "docker trust inspect"

Tags: docker, containers, dockerhub

I'm trying to determine which alpine image version on DockerHub I should use.

I saw the latest tag for alpine on DockerHub (as of 04/23/2021) is 3.13.5 so I ran this command:

```
$ docker trust inspect --pretty alpine:3.13.5

No signatures for alpine:3.13.5
```

I checked an older version of alpine and got this:

```
$ docker trust inspect --pretty alpine:3.12.1

Signatures for alpine:3.12.1

SIGNED TAG   DIGEST                                                            SIGNERS
3.12.1       c0e9560cda118f9ec63ddefb4a173a2b2a0347082d7dff7dc14272e7841a5b5a  (Repo Admin)
```

Does it mean I should not trust alpine:3.13.5 since there is no signer? Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image signing has [broken before in the past](https://github.com/docker-library/official-images/issues/5874) so I suspect this is just something down upstream at Docker (I'm pinging some of my contacts on this, but the weekend has already started for many so it might be a bit until they respond).

Notary version 1 hasn't had much uptake, which is why this can go so long with so few noticing it isn't working. We're actively working on a [Notary version 2](https://github.com/notaryproject/notaryproject) that will hopefully fix a lot of the issues that limited the adoption of version 1, but that will be a while until version 2 is GA and we can phase out version 1.

Until then, I suspect the latest alpine image is safe, and for added assurance, running the image through a vulnerability scanner would be a useful way to minimize risks. Particularly since the vulnerability scanner will indicate known vulnerabilities in old versions of an image that would still be signed.

Answer (score 0):

It has something to do with docker trust inspect. I have two different images for amd64/alpine with the same image id, and it shows different results.

```
$ docker image ls
    amd64/alpine   3.16.2   9c6f07244728   6 months ago   5.54MB    
    alpine         3.16.2   9c6f07244728   6 months ago   5.54MB

$ docker trust inspect --pretty alpine:3.16.2
    
    Signatures for alpine:3.16.2
    
    SIGNED TAG   DIGEST                                                             SIGNERS
    3.16.2       65a2763f593ae85fab3b5406dc9e80f744ec5b449f269b699b5efd37a07ad32e   (Repo Admin)
    
    Administrative keys for alpine:3.16.2
    
      Repository Key:       5a46c9aaa82ff150bb7305a2d17d0c521c2d784246807b2dc611f436a69041fd
      Root Key:     a2489bcac7a79aa67b19b96c4a3bf0c675ffdf00c6d2fabe1a5df1115e80adce

$ docker trust inspect --pretty amd64/alpine:3.16.2
No signatures or cannot access amd64/alpine:3.16.2
```